# How can one use <input type='file'> in Safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, file-upload

I was find around 1 week.help me pls TvT

Answer (score 12):

Granted we're WAAAAAAY past the relevance of this post, but it's nice to know that iOS6 does allow `<input type="file" />` and will allow you to select files from your camera roll.

Comment: We're not in any way past the relevance. Hybrid apps are becoming ever more popular and powerful. File uploads are one of the HTML features that are useful in that context.

Answer (score 8):

iPhone Safari doesn't support file uploads.

This is because iOS doesn't really have the concept of a file, at the user interface level. It is an inherent limitation of the UI that there isn't a user-facing filesystem through which files may be manually exchanged between apps.

You would have to persuade the user to install a custom app to do it. ([existing](http://picupapp.com/) [examples](http://www.cliqcliq.com/support/quickpic/))

Comment: I looked for official Apple documentation, that says this limitation, but cannot find it... anyone knows?

Comment: this is no longer valid, since ios 6 iphone does support file upload

Answer (score 6):

Agreed iOS 6.X solved this issue here you will find code, screenshots and tech limitations i.e: limitations (i.e> no audio files support, no live streaming video support)

[iOS 6 New Features (supporting input type file)](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers)

[image]