# jQuery Image Size and Type validation on Mobile Browsers

Tags: jquery, image, validation, mobile, browser

I'm a little stuck - I have some jQuery code for validating the filesize and type of image file being uploaded.  It works fine on normal browswers, but for some reason it does not work on mobile browsers (iPhones, Galaxies, etc).  Can anyone see where the problem is and how to fix it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.close_btn').click(function () {
        $('.grey_cover', window.parent.document).hide();
        $('.upload_photo_frame', window.parent.document).hide();
    });
    $("#file").change(function (event) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var kb = 1024;
        var size = (file.size/kb).toFixed(2);
        //alert(size);
        if (size > (1024 * 2)) {
            $('.upload_photo_div').hide();
            $('.photo_oversize_div').show();
            $('.photo_oversize_div .close_btn').click(function () {             
                $('.grey_cover', window.parent.document).hide();
                $('.photo_window',window.parent.document).hide();
            });
            $('.photo_oversize_div .confirm_btn').click(function () {
                $('.upload_photo_div').show();
                $('.photo_oversize_div').hide();
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $('#file').replaceWith($('#file').clone());
                } else {
                    $('#file').val('');
                }
            });
        }
        if (file.type != 'image/jpg' && file.type != 'image/jpeg' && file.type != 'image/png' && file.type != 'image/gif') {
            //$('.photo_format').text(file.type);
            $('.upload_photo_div').hide();
            $('.photo_format_error_div').show();
            $('.photo_format_error_div .close_btn').click(function () {             
                $('.grey_cover',window.parent.document).hide();
                $('.photo_window',window.parent.document).hide();
            });
            $('.photo_format_error_div .confirm_btn').click(function () {
                $('.upload_photo_div').show();
                $('.photo_format_error_div').hide();
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $('#file').replaceWith($('#file').clone());
                } else {
                    $('#file').val('');
                }
            });
        }
        // alert($('#file').val());
        // CheckFile(event.target.value);
    });
    $('.send_btn').click(function () {
        $('.upload_photo_div').hide();
        //$('.grey_cover').show();
        $('.loading_animation').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please take a look around... found this in five seconds on a search for "input type file iOS" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510306/how-can-one-use-input-type-file-in-safari-on-iphone ... short answer is that iOS (before iOS 6, apparently... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637303/clear-ios-6-input-type-file-image-thumbnail) doesn't support file uploads. (iOS 6 allows you to browse images from the photo library, but that's all.) Can't say why Galaxy wouldn't support, as Android is not shy about letting users poke around its filesystem.

Comment: If you have access to a Mac, and an iOS device, you could look at the Safari Web Inspector and look at the Console remotely to see if the page throws any errors while this script tries to run, btw. http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: I was asking about all mobile browsers, not just iOS, why the down vote?  You yourself don't know why it doesn't work on Galaxies.

Comment: My apologies, I took it off.

Comment: You did, however, specifically mention iPhones as being a target, btw, but did not detail what you've done to try to narrow down the list of possible culprits. If you tested (or had someone test) on an < iOS6 device, then my first answer is at least useful in that context. Without knowing what else you've done to try to debug this, it doesn't appear at first glance to be problematic. Unfortunately, due to the nature of mobile dev on Android, it's MUCH harder to see what's happening "under the hood" so you end up having to do things like doc-write out to a visible div to see where it breaks.